# NgFor exception with CORS request

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I use CORS requests in my app.

My service is:

```
getDatabaseFromServer(): any 
{

  return this.http.get(API_URL + '/mobile_api/task_list');

}
```

My component is:

```
 ngOnInit() {

this.items = this.AppConfigService.getDatabaseFromServer().subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.items = data['tasks'];
});
```

Template:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">   
....
</ion-item>
```

My server gets 2 requests OPTIONS and GET.

In case of OPTION it returns:

```
{"status": 0, "tasks": []}
```

In case of GET it returns:

```
{"status": 0, "tasks": [{...},{...}...]}
```

In browser I can see everything OK and correct list but in browser's consol I got NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reassign `items`

Do:

```
this.AppConfigService.getDatabaseFromServer().subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.items = data['tasks'];
})
```

Instead of

```
this.items = this.AppConfigService.getDatabaseFromServer().subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.items = data['tasks'];
}) // this will make items of type subscription
```

Side note: Your statement for Options request doesn't make sense, IMK Options doesn't return any body, just the headers and status code.